# can't render react-modal as reusable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I have an app with a list of meal, and clicking on a meal should make a modal appear on the screen with further information about the meal.

So I am trying to code a basic modal as a reusable component using the `react-modal` package.

However when I try to 'activate' the modal it does not work. the `openModal` method does get fired but the modal does not show up on the screen.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import MealCard from './MealCard';
import MealModal from './MealModal';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false
    }
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);

  };

  openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
    console.log(this.state.modalIsOpen);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="app-wrapper" style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              {[...Array(20)].map((x, i) =>
                  <div className="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 " key={i} onClick={this.openModal}>
                    <MealCard />
                  </div>
                )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <MealModal isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MealModal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const customStyles = {
  content : {
    top                   : '50%',
    left                  : '50%',
    right                 : 'auto',
    bottom                : 'auto',
    marginRight           : '-50%',
    transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
  }
};

Modal.setAppElement('#app')

export default class MealModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalId: 0,
      modalIsOpen: false
    };

    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({modalId: 3})
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.props.modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
        style={customStyles}
        contentLabel="Meal Modal"
      >
        <div className="modal-wrapper">
          <div className="container text-center">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <h2>ID of this modal is {this.state.modalId}</h2>
            <h3>This is an awesome modal.</h3>
            <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `isOpen` as props and using `modalIsOpen` (props) in `MealModal` component.

As mentioned in the comment, you can just use `isOpen={this.props.isOpen}`. There's no sense to use two states for serving the same purpose, one is `modalIsOpen` in `App` component and other is `modalIsOpen` in `MealModel` component

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer ! so how should I change this ? should I just put `isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}` in `MealModal.js` ?

Comment: @JulesCorb Write `isOpen={this.props.isOpen}` in `MealModal.js`

Comment: oh yeah right got it ! it does work now thank you :)

Comment: You can just use `isOpen={this.props.isOpen}`. There's no sense to use two states for serving the same purpose, one is `modalIsOpen` in `App` component and other is `modalIsOpen` in `MealModel` component.

Comment: @JulesCorb I hope the provided solution solves your issue. If that is the case then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/362322) the answer as it is a SO way to say thanks. :)

Comment: @AtulKhanduri I just did ! had to wait a few minutes before being able to accept. You should edit your post and add Tholl's answer in case other people end up here with the same problem. Thank you very much for your help anyway :)